# SharePoint programatically access error: AADSTS65001 DelegationDoesNotExist The user or administrator has not consented to use the app with ID X

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365

I’m using office365-rest-python-client to programmatically access a SharePoint site in Office365 online.

The application I’m acceding  this is just a Python script that will run in a backend
 For that, I went to https://entra.microsoft.com/ admin center and did the following:

- 1- Create an app in Applications > App Registration
- 2- Added a Secret
  to that application
- 3- Granted Permission to that application to
  access SharePoint API
- 4- Granted admin consent

Then using office365-rest-python-client , I used the application clientId and the SecretValue to send a request to add a page

The request fails with the following error showing in the Audit Logs in Microsoft Office365 Entra   :

```
Based on the information you provided we have identified following issue and recommend taking the action to resolve the issue.
Error Code: 65001
Message: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID ''(). Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
```

Going deeper about this error in Microsoft Documentation it states

```
AADSTS65001 DelegationDoesNotExist - The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID X. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
```

The client side shows

`POST /sites/security/_api/contextInfo`

and

`POST /sites/security/_api/sitePages/pages`

returning

`401  client error  “Unauthorized for url : https://my-sharepoint/sites/security/_api/sitePages/pages`

What could be the cause of this issue ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used certificate authentication and it worked as specified on https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client/

Under

3. Using an Azure AD application (certificate credentials flow)

Documentation:

```
[Granting access via Azure AD App-Only][1]
[wiki][1]
```

Example: connect_with_client_certificate.py